# Vector overlap analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, overlay

I'm in the search of the right tool to accomplish the following tasks:

I have vector layer A,B,C and D.

I want to overlay vector layer A with B, C and D.

If, for example, vector layer B is overlapping vector layer A, I'd like to have this printed out in a new attribute field for example "A+B"='yes'. Same goes for C and D. So I expect to have three new fields in the attribute table of layer A which tell me if the layer B, C and D do overlap it with yes and no or 1 and 0. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you interested only if a layer overlaps another layer, or do you need to know per feature?

Comment: hey matt, it's per feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get pretty close with:

1. Merge vector layers. It will merge the four layers into one with a column named `layer` with the name of the layer, for example A,B,C or D
2. Union the merge with the merge as `input layer`, no `overlay layer`. It will create all existing overlapping geometries. For example where A and B overlap there will be one geometry with layer attribute A and another exactly the same with layer attribute B
3. Aggregate the output with `$geometry` as group by expression and concatenate `layer` as aggregate:
   [image]

The output will have a field with all overlapping layers as an attribute:
[image]

Comment: This looks like a similar approach to that following a merge and running the polygon self intersection tool from the SAGA tools in processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution!